# Get count of particular column depending on courseid in mysql

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

Hi guys i am trying to get the count of status column from my table. I have two tables one is `course` and the other one is `topics`.

Here is Course table:

[image]

Here is my Topics table:

[image]

So from topics table i would like to count the status for ex: courseid 1 has status (5)count 2 and courseid 2 has status (11) count 1

Here i have tried with this query but its not giving me the result what i am expecting.

```
    public function getTopicReports() {
   $this->db->select('count(t.status) as statuscount,t.topicName as topicname,c.coursename,t.status')
            ->from('topics as t')
            ->join('course as c', 't.courseId = c.id');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
}


Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [statuscount] => 3 [topicname] => topic for course123 [coursename] => course 123 [status] => 5 ) )
```

Can any one help me how to get the result.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add  `group_by` in your code

```
$this->db->select('count(t.status) as statuscount,t.topicName as topicname,c.coursename,t.status')
            ->from('topics as t')
            ->join('course as c', 't.courseId = c.id')
            ->group_by('t.courseId,t.status');
```

Comment: Hi I have one doubt may i ask

Comment: @suresh yes please.

Comment: if do you have idea about zend framework can you please guide me how to install in ubuntu